# Get Current Center Position Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Looking for a way to get the current coordinates of the center of a map using Mapbox GL JS the same way they do on Mapbox Studio (see below)

[Mapbox Studio Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYhLN.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

The [`Map#getCenter` method](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#getcenter) returns the coordinates of the center of the map.

Answer (score 2):

To get the current center position:

```js
map.current.getCenter();
    // return => {lat: 42.5232 , lng: -70.5552}
```

This is with React =>
but if you want to get the current position always that the map change, so added this method inside useEffect:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
      if (!map.current) return; // wait for map to initialize
      map.current.on('move', () => {
      setLng(map.current.getCenter().lng.toFixed(4));
      setLat(map.current.getCenter().lat.toFixed(4));
      setZoom(map.current.getZoom().toFixed(2));
      });
    });
```

[Dos getCenter REACT](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/use-mapbox-gl-js-with-react/#store-the-new-coordinates)